# will_paginate undefined method `total_pages'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

What am I missing here? I am using the haml_scaffold generator and the pages work fine with will_paginate. When I start tinkering I end up with this 'total_pages' error and I'm not sure what I am doing that is causing it. Anyone have any insight? 
I'm using mislav-will_paginate 2.3.11.

```
mike@jauntyjackalope:~/project$ script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.4)
>> @locations = Location.find_all_by_city("springfield")
=> [#<Location id: 3, address: "123 Main St", city: "springfield", phone: "321-1234", business_id: 2>]
>> @locations.class
=> Array
>> @locations.collect{|loc| loc.business}
=> [#<Business id: 2, name: "A Bar", website: "www.abar.com", business_owner_id: 1, created_at: "2009-08-31 21:13:10", updated_at: "2009-08-31 21:13:10">]
>> @locations.class
=> Array
>> @locations.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 2)
=> [#<Location id: 3, address: "123 Main St", city: "springfield", phone: "321-1234", business_id: 2>]
>> helper.will_paginate(@locations)
NoMethodError: undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0xb6f83bc4>
 from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mislav-will_paginate-2.3.11/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb:197:in `total_pages_for_collection'
 from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mislav-will_paginate-2.3.11/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb:98:in `will_paginate'
 from (irb):7

>> y @locations
--- 
- !ruby/object:Location 
  attributes: 
    city: springfield
    business_id: "2"
    id: "3"
    phone: 321-1234
    address: 123 Main St
  attributes_cache: {}

  business: !ruby/object:Business 
    attributes: 
      name: A Bar
      updated_at: 2009-08-31 21:13:10
      website: www.abar.com
      id: "2"
      created_at: 2009-08-31 21:13:10
      business_owner_id: "1"
    attributes_cache: {}

=> nil
>>
```

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Try to change

```
@locations.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 2)
```

to

```
@locations = @locations.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 2)
```

Comment: Ghaaa! I knew it was something dumb like that. Been staring at the screen to long. Sweet thanks!

Comment: Thanks Jirapong! You just solved my 5 hours problem!
Hint for others: If using searchlogic, trying to use search.paginate will throw errors. Using the .paginate method on the @whatever object you are actually searching for might help :-)

Comment: I have the following query, which looks similar to the solutions but it still throws the same error `@users = @company.users.page(params[:page]).sort_by {|u| u.cards.first.card_visits.count }.reverse` any tips?

Comment: switching the method from `page` to `paginate` gives me `can't dup NilClass` error on the same query.

Comment: paginate() a new array with paginatable but it didn't make @locations paginatable array.

Answer (score 29):

include

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

before loading that code will solve your problem.

Comment: where? in the view or the controller?

Comment: Add require 'will_paginate/array' to your controller. will_paginate works only on objects (not on array!) unless you're telling it to.

Comment: @Lior - i have added this in controller as well as i tries with creating an initializer, but still getting the same error

Answer (score 12):

If anyone else is having this problem. In my case I did not call the pagination in my controller method last.

**Example Before:**

```
@foo = Foo.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
@foo = Foo.do something
```

**Example After:**
I called the pagination last within my method since rails reads from top to bottom and it seemed to fix my error.

```
@foo = Foo.do something
@foo = Foo.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
```

Comment: I had a sort_by after "paginate" and this was causing this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
@locations = Location.paginate(:all, :conditions => 'city = springfield')
```

`@locations` must be an object

in your example `@locations` is an `Array`

array cant have total_pages method

Comment: will_paginate gives this method to the array class, if you call paginate on an array, it will convert it to will paginate collection, which have this method

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering a similar a error `undefined method 'total_pages' for ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation`.

It turns out that **renaming my variable** solved the issue.

Here was my code:

```
@reviews = @user.reviews.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).order('created_at DESC')
```

I changed it to this:

```
@user_reviews = @user.reviews.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).order('created_at DESC')
```

And it solved the issue. It's very bizarre but it there may have been some kind of conflict.

Since I spent a few hours researching, I thought it might help someone one day as well!