# undefined method `total_pages' for ActiveRecord_Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have seen a couple of questions on this and tried them but it doesn't help. I am using will_paginate 3.0.7 gem. Where exactly am I going wrong?

Here is my code:

Categories_controller.rb:

```
def show
  @category = Category.includes(:products).find(params[:categoryid])
  @products = @category.products.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end
```

_product.html.erb

```
<%= will_paginate %>
  <ul class="categories">
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to product.productname,product %>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Thank you

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do? Is ther a has_many belongs_to relationship between Category Product? Can you show models code.

Comment: Yes, it does. In Class Product I have "belongs_to :category" and in Class Category I have "has_many :products"

Comment: can you breakpoint just after @category and print out its content

Comment: With out will_paginate in _product.html.erb I could print the products of each category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `@products` as an argument to `will_paginate`. Also, missed to end your loop. Try this:

```
<%= will_paginate @products %>
<ul class="categories">
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to product.productname,product %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue with the exact same type of naming and structure. Renaming the variable actually fixed it. So instead of:

```
  @products = @category.products.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

You may want to try this:

```
  @category_products = @category.products.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62977623/11293450.