# Search box in ruby on rails not displaying results with pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate, search-form

I'm working with Ruby on Rails, trying to get my search bar to display the results, but whenever I had pagination to the products index page I'll have the following error:[image]

My search form:

```
<div class="navbar-form navbar-right search-form" role="search">
    <div class="input-group add-on">
        <%= form_with(url: products_path, method: 'get', local: true) do |form| %>
        <%= form.text_field :q, id: 'q', class:"form-control", placeholder: "Search ...", value: params[:q] %>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <%= form.submit 'Go', class:"btn btn-default", id:"btn-search"%>
        </div><!-- input-group-btn -->
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my Views I have:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <%= will_paginate @products, inner_window: 1, outter_window: 0 %>
</div>
```

My Products controller:

```
def index
    if params[:q]
      search_term = params[:q]
      @products = Product.search(search_term)
    else
      @products = Product.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 6)
    end
  end
```

My Products model:

```
def self.search(search_term)
    if Rails.env.production?
      Product.where("name ilike ?", "%#{search_term}%")
    else
      Product.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search_term}%")
    end
  end
```

any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408852/will-paginate-undefined-method-total-pages)

Answer (score 0):

Should be `Product.search(search_term).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 6)` in your index action.